# Reload all images on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all the images in the page to reload including `backgound-image:` rules

I have some semi working code but I want to know if there is an easier way of doing this.

```
function cacheBuster(url) {
    return url.replace(/\?cacheBuster=\d*/, "") + "?cacheBuster=" + new Date().getTime().toString();
}

$("img").each(function() {
    this.src = cacheBuster(this.src);
});

$("*").each(function() {
    var bg_img = $(this).css("background-image");
    if (bg_img !== "none") {
        var url = /url\((.*)\)/i.exec(bg_img);
        if (url) {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + cacheBuster(url[1]) + ")");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Would have suggested filtering `*` with `hasAttribute` selector but then, it may not work on css backed elements.

Comment: Looks good to me too. I don't know of other alternatives. I added some noise to the image url (like img.png?).

Comment: The user might see the images flicker once when the browser loads the new images from the server, or the images might disappear for a while depending on how fast the connection is.

Comment: that won't be an issue for my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine but you are missing inputs with type=image, that is images that act as a submit button. You can include them by adding following code

```
$("img, input[type=image]").each(function() {
    this.src = cacheBuster(this.src);
});
```

Also you can change the code where you loop through all elements, just to include visible ones, if it is acceptable in your case.

```
$("*:visible")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: considering there is probably no better solution and this did help, you might as well get it.